# How to detect which websites the user is viewing or connecting to

Tags: python, filter, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture

I'm writing a Python application that, among other things, needs to know which websites the user is looking at in the web browser or otherwise connecting to on OS X and, if possible, Linux. This is to track how long the user is accessing certain websites.

I know that on OS X there is a Cocoa call which returns the current page in Safari, but this must also work with Chrome and Firefox at a minimum, ideally with any client, known or unknown to the software.

The first thing I've looked into is [pcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) via [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) which I can use in Python with [pylibpcap](http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net/). pcap is for packet capture, and in theory as I understand, I could detect whether packets are flowing to/from certain "black-listed" IP addresses. This would sort of work, but if a static web-page were open in the browser and left as is, I would not be able to detect it via this mechanism.

First, will I even be able to do what I've described above with libpcap? I'm a beginner with network filtering and the like, so I'm not entirely sure.

Second, is there a better way to do this?

(The app TimeSink for OS X has an interesting approach, which is to look at what is displayed in the title bar to decide which website the user is browsing. This is not ideal for me for two reasons: (1) I may not be able to conclusively decide what domain is being visited by the title and (2) I can only see the title of the active tab.)

[image]

Comment: The obvious place here seems to be to hook into DNS lookups.

Comment: @Lattyware hm, any clue as to how to do this? I'm coming up empty with Google searches.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe to use [Twisted proxy](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/twisted.web.proxy.Proxy.html) and pass all browsers through it?

You will be able to analyse HTTP headers and extract relevant information.

Here is an example: https://github.com/nbareil/twisted-proxy

Comment: Thanks, will check this out. Looks promising.